# Creating a survey application in angularjs

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I would like to create a survey application in angular js, however as im more experienced in jquery im not sure of angulars capabilities. For example, users can define questions in another part of the system, such as: question title, question type(radiobuttonlist, freetext etc), and the options for that type if its a radiobuttonlist or dropdown etc. This would mean that angular would need to pick up the question type and then render the relevent element, for example if the question type is a radio button list then render it out with the options brought back from the database. If it's a freetext area then render a textarea etc. How possible is this in angular or would it be better for me to do it in jquery. I'm just a bit weary about the speed that jquery would run at compared to angular.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that is  very easy with Angular js, based on your question type you can render respective element::
i.e. you are having all your questions in `$scope.questions` variable.

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions">
   <div ng-if="question.type=='text'">
      <input type="text" ng-model="question.answer"/>
   </div>
   <div ng-if="question.type=='textArea'">
      <textarea ng-model="question.answer"/>
   </div>
   <div ng-if="question.type=='dropdown'">
      <select ng-model="question.answer" ng-options="option as option.text for option in question.options "></select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to ask i've got a bit of polishing up on angular to do but how would you go about saving results based off that code you've provided?

Comment: Result for first question will get stored in you $scope.questions[0].answer and so own.